# What are the disadvantages of using inheritance as a way of reusing code?

Tags: inheritance, code-reuse

What are the disadvantages of using inheritance as a way of reusing code?

Comment: Isn't it in your textbook somewhere?

Comment: What happens when you want to inherit functionality from more than one class, but your language doesn't support multiple inheritance?

Comment: C++ supports multiple inheritage
java supports that with the use of interfaces
No idea about others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using inheritance to achieve code reuse suffers from the following problems:

1. You cannot change the reused behaviour at runtime. Inheritance is a compile-time dependency, so if a `GameClient` class inherits from `TCPSocket` to reuse the `connect()` and `write()` member functions, it has the TCP functionality hardcoded. You cannot change this at runtime.
2. You cannot replace the reused behaviour from the outside for the sake of testing. If a `GameClient` class inherits from `TCPSocket` so that it gets `write()` (for writing data to a socket), you cannot exchange this code from the outside. You cannot plug in a different write() function which logs all data which `GameClient` wants to write to a file or so.
3. You are dependant on multiple inheritance for all but the most simple applications. This opens the door for [diamond shaped inheritance trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) which increase the code complexity a lot.

Preferring composition over inheritance to reuse code avoids all these issues.

Answer (score 6):

IIRC, the ***Liskov Substitution Principle*** <sup>**1)**</sup> postulates that one should be able to substitute a class by any of its derived classes; that is, derived classes should not behave radically different than, or violate the contract set up by their base classes.

Obviously then, this principle puts an intentional limit on how a (base) class can be "re-used" by another class (which is derived from it). Other means of using a class, such as aggregation or composition, aren't thus limited by the principle.

---

<sup>**1)** See e.g. [*The Liskov Substitution Principle*](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf) (links to a PDF document).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Using inheritance means that when you call a method (or virtual method in C++) in the same class, it isn't immediately clear that you might actually be calling a subclass' method. A code smell that can result is a call stack that goes up and down the class hierarchy, which effectively means that your superclass and subclass are in a circular dependency.

Using composition and interfaces makes it clear that there are multiple possible implementations, and also makes it obvious when there is a circular dependency (which should generally be removed).

(Composition makes circular dependencies obvious for a couple of reasons (assuming you use pass dependencies of a class in via the constructor). If A and B depend on each other, then either A constructs B and passes `this` or `self` into B's constructor, which is a clear sign of circular dependency, or some other class constructs both A and B, which turns out to be impossible since A requires B to be constructed first, and B requires A to be constructed first.)

Answer (score 0):

It requires inheritance (to be reflective about it), which is only one of many possible structures for code. That's why we have procedural programming, functional programming, object-oriented programming, aspect-oriented programming, declarative programming, etc. See [programming paradigms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm).

Answer (score 0):

If you use inheritance, you get tied into a mutable-state object-oriented paradigm. If you try to use immutable objects instead, you end up writing [pseudocode]

```
class A (int X, int Y)
    def self.nextX(int nextX) = A(newX, self.Y)

class B (int X, int Y, int Z) extends A(X, Y)
    def self.nextX(int nextX) = B(newX, self.Y, self.Z)
```

and there isn't code reuse. Thus, you use mutable objects, and madness ensues :).